# How to convert rows with different values into different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns something like this:

```
+----+------+-------------------+
| ID | Type |      Address      |
+----+------+-------------------+
|  1 |    0 | Some address text |
|  1 |    1 | Some address text |
|  1 |    3 | Some address text |
|  2 |    0 | Some address text |
|  2 |    1 | Some address text |
+----+------+-------------------+
```

The number of types is fixed. There is up to three of them. ID is not unique within this table, it can't be more than three of the though (one type per ID). What I want is to create a table as follows:

```
+----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| ID |   AddressType0    |   AddressType1    |   AddressType2    |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | Some address text | Some address text | Some address text |
|  2 | Some address text | Some address text | Some address text |
|  3 | Some address text | Some address text | Some address text |
|  4 | Some address text | Some address text | Some address text |
|  5 | Some address text | Some address text | Some address text |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

In the resulting table ID should be unique. If there is no address of appropriate type in the original table, the resulting table should contains null in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
with cte as (
     <query here> 
)
select row_number() over (order by id) as id, 
       max(case when type = 0 then address end) as [AddressType0],
       max(case when type = 1 then address end) as [AddressType1],
       max(case when type = 2 then address end) as [AddressType2]
from cte c
group by id;
```

Comment: That works perfectly. It's epic that you've handled it so fast. Thanks a lot and thanks for fixings my initially broken tables. :)

Comment: Also, I don't actually need cte for this. I could just round my original query into another braces and use these max() and group by.